# NodejS fs with authentication on accessing shared directory from cloud

Tags: node.js, azure, fs, nfs

We're using node fs to access Files from NFS Network Drive. While testing locally, it works fine as it tries to access the NFS using my credentials in the background.

When I deploy the same code in cloud, it fails as my credentials are not present.The point is, to access the shared directory, I need to authenticate in the fs part.

So, I am looking for a way to solve this problem by giving credentials upon accessing or any other ways.
Somehow I need to supply username/password/domain because this file requires special permission. Is it possible to supply permissions somehow? For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = '\\someserver\stuff\names.txt';
var credentials = { username:'mydomain/jsmith', password:'password' }; ???

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Note: Any solutions apart from mounting pls.

Comment: Just mount the location from the OS. This can be done in node.js or form you per hand.
Spawn the moun command with nodes `child_process` module and then you can read the stuff from the mount location with `fs`

Comment: @Marc: I'm looking for something other than mounting. Also, can you pls. share a snippet to create a child_process which uses credentials of a service account?

Comment: Its exactly the same from command line. You did not say what OS you are using. But why should i provide a possible solution when you want to use something else?

Answer (score 0):

NFS stands for [Network File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System).

the node built in module `fs` also stands for [File System](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Usually, to work with a `file system` you first need to mount it. Not just an FTP server that work with the file system by itself.

The npm package [node-nfsc](https://github.com/scality/node-nfsc) first mount it, then allow you to browse.

You didn't explain what is your restriction, and why you want to avoid mounting.

If working with `fs` module is not a requirement, you can drop a middleware service that will mount the NFS (with all the restriction you need) and provide http\ftp\scp\etc access without any mounting in the node.

P.S. The wiki page mention webNFS as a version that allowing to function ... without the complexity of Portmap and MOUNT protocols, but I didn't find any way to use it.